# Mockito's `thenReturn` returns `null` instead of Pair(null."text") when called by tested class and not directly

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

Testing and Mockito beginner here, so I hope it's just some simple error.
EDIT it's most likely due to the functions being `suspend` functions

My test is crashing beacause `Mockito` returns `null` where it should return non-nullable `Pair`. In live environment this code works fine (no NPE), but I cannot make the test pass with Mockito.
Troubling mock:

```
val mks = mock(MyKeyStore::class.java)
`when`(mks.createKeyStore(user,pass)).thenReturn(Pair(null, "userExists"))
```

`MyKeyStore.createKeyStore()` returns non-nullable `Pair`

```
suspend fun createKeyStore(user: String, ksPass: String): Pair<KeyStore?, String>
```

`mks.createKeyStore()` is called by `UserRepo.createUser()`
UserRepo crashes beacuse the test considers `ksResult == null`, which by defintion is non-nullable. When I change it to nullable the code doesn't compile at all, so I'm thinking it's related to Mockito setup.

```kotlin
class UserRepo(private val myKeyStore: MyKeyStore) {
    suspend fun createUser(user: String, p0: String, p1: String): Pair<Boolean, String> =
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            return@withContext if (p0 == p1) {
                val ksResult = myKeyStore.createKeyStore(user, p0)
                ksResult.first?.let { //line where NPE crash leads
                    val keyResult = myKeyStore.createKeyDB(user, p0)
                    keyResult.first?.let { Pair(true, keyResult.second) } ?: run { Pair(false, keyResult.second) }
                } ?: run { Pair(false, ksResult.second) }
            } else Pair(false, myKeyStore.mPasswordsNotMatching)
        }
}
```

full test

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun createUserFailDueToUserExisting() = runBlocking() {
        val user = "user"
        val pass = "pass"
        val mks = mock(MyKeyStore::class.java)
        `when`(mks.createKeyStore(user,pass)).thenReturn(Pair(null, "userExists"))
        println(mks.createKeyStore(user,pass)) // this actually prints the pair correctly
        val repo = UserRepo(mks)
        val result = repo.createUser(user,pass,pass) // NPE crash, but why?
        assertFalse(result.first)
        assertTrue(result.second == "userExists")
    }
```

How can I configure the mock to return `Pair` rather than `null`?

Comment: try to step your test thru a debugger would be the best suggestion.

Comment: it's not, the issue was the functions being `suspend` functions and not specyfing dispatcher in the test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because the funtions are `suspend` functions, specyfing dispatcher in `runBlocking` fixed it for me
where I found an answer: [testing coroutines in Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMb0Fs8rCRs)

```
    @Test
    fun createUserFailDueToUserExisting() = runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val user = "user"
        val pass = "pass"
        val mks = mock(MyKeyStore::class.java)
        `when`(mks.createKeyStore(user, pass)).thenReturn(Pair(null, "userExists"))
        println(mks.createKeyStore(user, pass))
        val repo = UserRepo(mks)
        val result = repo.createUser(user, pass, pass)
        assertFalse(result.first)
        assertTrue(result.second == "userExists")
    }
```